# i want to create status and comment system similar to facebook

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to build comment and status system similar to facebook. when i give a status its show and comment regarding this status its show. but when i give a new status it dose not show.

```
<?php 

// show status.

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("saif");
$sql="select id, st from status ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id']. " " .$row['st'];
    echo "<br>";

    //show comment;

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("saif");
    $sql="select com from comment ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);


    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['com'];
        echo "<hr>";    
    }
    // end of show comment

   //new comment area.
   include('textarea.php');
   echo "<hr>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: There are many errors. I don't know what you want to achieve exactly, and it would be helpful to have some about your sql tables. And maybe a scratch of your final results.

Comment: Formatted and fixed grammar a bit.

Comment: i just want to build comment and status system similar to facebook. when i give a status its show and comment regarding this status its show.  but when i give a new status it dose not show.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is my solution:
First I create two tables in my db and I populated them, then I create a connection to my db using MySQLi (MySQL is deprecated).
I SELECTED all the status, and for each status I selected the related comments. To do so, In the comments table I need something to make a relation between status and comments. 
Just to understand to which status the comment is related.

First let's create and populate the tables:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `st` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `status` (`id`, `st`)
VALUES
    (1, 'This is the first status in your DB, let\'s say \"Hello World\"'),
    (2, 'This is the second status');


CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `com` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `comment` (`id`, `id_status`, `com`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'This is just a comment to the first status'),
    (2, 1, 'This is another comment to the first status'),
    (3, 2, 'This is a comment to the second status'),
    (4, 1, 'This is the third comment to the first status');
```

Ok, the php file:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDB");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Connection error: ".mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM status";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['id']." ".$row['st']."<br>";

//show comment
    echo "<ol>";
    $id_status = $row['id'];
    $query = "SELECT com FROM comment WHERE id_status = $id_status";
    $comments = $con->query($query);
    while($comment = $comments->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<li>".$comment['com']."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ol>";
// end of show comment

//new comment area.
    include('textarea.php');
    echo "<hr>";    
}
?>
```

And this is the result (no text area in my output, cause I didn't have your textarea.php)

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried. but only one status and comment show. others does not show.

Comment: Is your code online o are you working offline on your local pc ?

Comment: i m working with xamp. data insert is ok. but only one status and comment show. so there has a problem with view data.

Comment: can i use an " if " statement?

Comment: i just added "if(mysql_num_rows($comment)>0)" before 2nd " which" statement.